# ROBOCOPY /XN: newer in source or destination?

Tags: windows, robocopy

Does ROBOCOPY /XN exclude files that are newer in the SOURCE or files that are newer in the destination?

I checked Microsoft official documentation but it is totally ambiguous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that the [Robocopy](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) `/XN` switch excludes files that are newer in the source from being copied to the destination directory. So if there is a newer file in the source folder than what is in the destination folder and you use the `/XN` parameter, then the file(s) will not be copied to the destination folder—I tested and confirmed that this is the case by simply testing it from a test folder with older and newer files of the same file name so that's how I confirmed.

---

### Further Resources

- `Robocopy /?`

  - `/XN :: eXclude Newer files.`